# TIBCO BW How to get the request from web service and publish the same (XML) to EMS

Tags: xml, soap, tibco, ems, businessworks

I am a new to Tibco BW development and have a specific task to perform but have no clues how to.

I am creating a http SOAP web service in BW. I need to get the ONLY Request XML ( not the SOAP header) and then that request XML need to be published as is in EMS. Not sure how to do it. Any help/hint is appreciated.

Thanks 
DMEHA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i understand you want to put the payload of the SOAP request into a queue.
This could be simply done by the "render-xml()" function in the inputs of a JMS Text Message or using the XML Message Type with your WSDL request message schema in your Queue/Topic Sender.

Your process might be simply look like this:

[image]

On the input tab of the JMS Queue sender you need to map the request (here samplerequest) into the Text "body" with the render-xml function. This will "render" your XML tree as text into the JMS message body.

Should look somehow like this:

[image]

Hope that helps

Cheers
       Seb